# VBS Regex pattern word space word

Tags: regex, vbscript

I would like to keep "Document Brasil" in a list from the following pattern in VBS:

```
<Document FormTypeName="Document Brasil">
```

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. :

```
objReg.Pattern = "Document FormTypeName=""(.+\.\s.+\.)"""
```

Matches return 0. Which is the correct regular expression to catch only "Document Brasil"? 
 **Word *space* Word** ?

Comment: There is no dot in `Document Brasil` and you require it with `\.`. Remove the two `\.`. Word is matched with `\w+`, BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the rules for attributes, I'd search for a sequence of non-" between "s. As in:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "<Document FormTypeName=""([^""]*)"">"
>> WScript.Echo ">" & r.Execute("<Document FormTypeName=""Document Brasil"">")(0).Submatches(0) & "<"
>>
>Document Brasil<
```